# excel: object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim cht As Chart
Dim Xleft As Double, Ytop As Double
Xleft = cht.PlotArea.InsideLeft
```

i am getting this error on the third line. does anyone know why?

here is the full code. please keep in mind that this is excel 2003

```
Sub DrawSmoothTransparentShapesOnRadarChart()
      Dim cht As Chart
      Set cht = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)

      Dim srs As Series
      Dim iSrs As Long
      Dim Npts As Integer, Ipts As Integer
      Dim myShape As Shape
      Dim Xnode As Double, Ynode As Double
      Dim Rmax As Double, Rmin As Double
      Dim Xleft As Double, Ytop As Double
      Dim Xwidth As Double, Yheight As Double
      Dim dPI As Double
      Dim iFillColor As Long
      Dim iLineColor As Long

      Set cht = ActiveChart
      Xleft = cht.PlotArea.InsideLeft
      Xwidth = cht.PlotArea.InsideWidth
      Ytop = cht.PlotArea.InsideTop
      Yheight = cht.PlotArea.InsideHeight
      Rmax = cht.Axes(2).MaximumScale
      Rmin = cht.Axes(2).MinimumScale
      dPI = WorksheetFunction.Pi()

      For iSrs = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count

        Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(iSrs)

        Select Case srs.ChartType
          Case xlRadar, xlRadarFilled, xlRadarMarkers

            Npts = srs.Points.Count

            Xnode = Xleft + Xwidth / 2 * _
                (1 + (srs.Values(Npts) - Rmin) / (Rmax - Rmin) _
                * Sin(2 * dPI * (Npts - 1) / Npts))

            Ynode = Ytop + Yheight / 2 * _
                (1 - (srs.Values(Npts) - Rmin) / (Rmax - Rmin) _
                * Cos(2 * dPI * (Npts - 1) / Npts))

            With cht.Shapes.BuildFreeform _
                (msoEditingAuto, Xnode, Ynode)
              For Ipts = 1 To Npts

                Xnode = Xleft + Xwidth / 2 * _
                    (1 + (srs.Values(Ipts) - Rmin) / (Rmax - Rmin) _
                    * Sin(2 * dPI * (Ipts - 1) / Npts))

                Ynode = Ytop + Yheight / 2 * _
                    (1 - (srs.Values(Ipts) - Rmin) / (Rmax - Rmin) _
                    * Cos(2 * dPI * (Ipts - 1) / Npts))

                .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, _
                    Xnode, Ynode
              Next
              Set myShape = .ConvertToShape
            End With

            For Ipts = 1 To Npts
              myShape.Nodes.SetEditingType 3 * Ipts - 2, msoEditingSmooth
            Next

            Select Case iSrs
              Case 1
                iFillColor = 44
                iLineColor = 12
              Case 2
                iFillColor = 45
                iLineColor = 10
              Case 3
                iFillColor = 43
                iLineColor = 17
            End Select

            With myShape
              .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = iFillColor
              .Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = iLineColor
              .Line.Weight = 1.5
              .Fill.Transparency = 0.5
            End With
        End Select
      Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set cht to a chart object.

EDIT In the light of the code above, I think you will find that your problems go away if you select a chart.

```
Sub DrawSmoothTransparentShapesOnRadarChart()
      Dim cht As Chart
      ''Delete this line, or comment it:
      ''Set cht = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)

      Dim srs As Series
      Dim iSrs As Long
      Dim Npts As Integer, Ipts As Integer
      Dim myShape As Shape
      Dim Xnode As Double, Ynode As Double
      Dim Rmax As Double, Rmin As Double
      Dim Xleft As Double, Ytop As Double
      Dim Xwidth As Double, Yheight As Double
      Dim dPI As Double
      Dim iFillColor As Long
      Dim iLineColor As Long

      ''This line set cht equal to the selected chart
      Set cht = ActiveChart
```

Comment: it says unable to get chartobjects property of the worksheets class

Comment: Do you have a chart on worksheet1? You can change (1) to the name of the worksheet and the name of the chart, for example, ("Sheet1").

Comment: thank you. i did not have a chart. i added a chart. and now it says TYPE MISMATCH on the same line

Comment: thanks, im getting object doesnt support this method on Xleft = cht.PlotArea.InsideLeft

Comment: remou i am getting application defined or object defined error on this even after doing what you said on  Xleft = cht.PlotArea.InsideLeft

Comment: What chart type are you using? I have tried two versions of Excel and it works.

Comment: i am just adding a blank chart. i click on the chart icon and press finish

Comment: Just for the sake of experiment, create, say, a barchart from scratch data and then try.